# Windows 8 Desktop App - How do I pull in data from my Facebook/Twitter and YouTube feeds?

Tags: xpath, windows-8, desktop-application

I want to make a personalized Windows 8 App.

How do I pull in data from my Facebook/Twitter and YouTube feeds?

I managed to do this on a website easily in PHP using "$xpath->query" but as I can't use PHP for this I am wondering what I should be looking into instead.

I have tried researching xpath support for Windows Desktop Apps but was unable to find anything helpful.

Would this be easiest to do with Javascript/C++/C# or VB? What is the function I should be looking in to?

Sorry for such a nooby question, but I have spent several hours researching and I am still none the wiser.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have already managed to retrieve the data in XML format and you're now looking for a way to parse it.

If you'll be using C# or VB, you don't have an XPath implementation available, but you can use LINQ to XML instead. It has a different syntax, but you can achieve pretty much the same with it.

There's a [tutorial available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx), as well as a [sample for download](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XLinq-XmlReader-and-1e17c0a5). This should be enough to get you started.